# Convert DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM into date

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I need to transfer a date time read in as a character from a CSV and convert it to a POSIXct format.

I can successfully do with dates only but have been unable to do this for a date and a time combined character string, the time.

```
time <-('01/08/2014 16:25')
as.POSIXct(time, origin = "03/01/1950 00:00", tz = "GMT")
[1] "0001-08-20 GMT"
class(time2)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: The year format "%Y" needs to be capped if you have 4 Y-digits.

Answer (score 4):

```
time <-("01/08/2014 16:25:00")
time2 <- strptime(time,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S",tz="GMT")
[1] "2014-08-01 16:25:00 GMT"
```

I was unaware that the %Y has to be capped for 4 digits!